# How to add intersection vertices to a ShapelyLinestring?

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, linestring

Assume that I have two shapely LineStrings. I want to find their intersection and then **add the intersection point as vertices into the respective LineStrings**.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

# Create two LineStrings which intersect at (2,2)
l1 = LineString([[1,1],[3,3]])
l2 = LineString([[1,3],[3,1]])

# Find the intersection of the two lines
newvtx  = l1.intersection(l2)
```

In this case this would be easy to do manually, but is there a way to do so automatically for more complicated LineStrings?

Comment: It is not possible to do it automatically. You have to manually insert the vertex into the line. In particular, if the line is complex, snapping may be required. You should also consider the error due to floating point.

Comment: @Urban87: Actually, turns out it is possible to automate this process. I have shown the answer I found below.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found the solution to this problem. You can use project to snap the point to the LineString and find the distance along the string, then use the [cut function](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/465156#file_cut.py) to cut the line. One may then combine the two separate LineStrings into a shared LineString. I have attached a code snippet below:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString, Point
from shapely.ops import linemerge, snap

def cut(line, distance):
    # Cuts a line in two at a distance from its starting point
    if distance <= 0.0 or distance >= line.length:
        return [LineString(line)]
    coords = list(line.coords)
    for i, p in enumerate(coords):
        pd = line.project(Point(p))
        if pd == distance:
            return [
                LineString(coords[:i+1]),
                LineString(coords[i:])]
        if pd > distance:
            cp = line.interpolate(distance)
            return [
                LineString(coords[:i] + [(cp.x, cp.y)]),
                LineString([(cp.x, cp.y)] + coords[i:])]

# Create two LineStrings which intersect at (2,2)
l1 = LineString([[1,1],[3,3]])
l2 = LineString([[1,3],[3,1]])

# Find the intersection of the two lines
newvtx  = l1.intersection(l2)

cut_l1 = cut(
    line        = l1,
    distance    = l1.project(newvtx))

cut_l1 = MultiLineString([cut_l1[0],cut_l1[1]])

l1 = linemerge(cut_l1)
```

Comment: Does the code above work on cases when the two input linestrings do not intersect? If not, you might want to perform some sort of check and find a way to handle that case.